# find keyboard is visible using jquery

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

Hi I have developed android phonegap app which is responsive.So when keyboard is visible i need to hide the footer in portrait and landscape mode and keyboard is not visible i need to show the footer in both the mode.I have tried the sample but its not working fine.If i open the app in portrait mode i cant able to find the footer in landscape mode when keyboard is not visible.

Here is my sample code:

```
var is_keyboard = false;
var is_landscape = false;
var initial_screen_size = window.innerHeight;

/* Android */
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
is_keyboard = (window.innerHeight < initial_screen_size);
is_landscape = (screen.height < screen.width);
if (is_keyboard) 
{
    $("#footer1").hide();
}
else
{
    $("#footer1").show();
}

}, false);
```

Please guide me.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best bet is to register for the show and hide keyboard events.

```
document.addEventListener("showkeyboard", function() {
    $("#footer1").hide();
}, false);

document.addEventListener("hidekeyboard", function() {
    $("#footer1").show();
}, false);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.I have tried this in phonegap 2.1 and its working fine.Can this work in latest phonegap version cordova-2.3

Comment: Hi Simon - are these events part of PhoneGap/Cordova "core" or do they come from a 3rd party plugin?  I've seen mention of these in a few different places, but I'm having trouble finding where these come from.  Thanks!