# How to detect if drop down list is open in Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, drop-down-menu

I need to detect if the drop-down list is currently present in the screen to hide the footer of the app.
I found this solution for the keyboard:

```
document.addEventListener("showkeyboard", function() {
    $("#footer1").hide();
}, false);
```

source: [find keyboard is visible using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581693/find-keyboard-is-visible-using-jquery)

Now I'm looking for a way to detect the drop down list. Thanks. 
 Sample image:

[image: Drop down list]

Comment: Can you please provide code snippet to show the drop down list.?

Comment: @jeek online It's just the usual `<select></select>` element, is it really necessary to show that code? when tapped, it opens the phone's default drop down list. I'll attach an image in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("<your selector of select tag>").click( function () {

  $('#footer1').toggle();

});
```