# Chose how Android Keyboard acts on mobile website

Tags: android, html, ios, css

So I am having some issues with programming my mobile website.  Right now everything works well on iphone browser, however my coworker's phone (android) does this thing where when the keyboard is brought up, all the content gets scrunched together.

I'm using vw and vh (view width and view height) for styling my webpage element sizes.  I'm guessing that the view gets suqeezed down?

Can I somehow disable this from the website-side of things?

If not, how can I make it so that when the keyboard comes up, my elements don't change size?

Thanks,
:)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could check for keyboard opens with this method [find keyboard is visible using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581693/find-keyboard-is-visible-using-jquery)
and then fix the height and width to some dynamic max values which you can remove after the user closes the keyboard.